# typeerror string indices must be integers not str python

Tags: python

I have defined a function `get_class_average()` having one argument "students". `students` is a list of 3 students: lloyd, alice, tyler, which are indirectly dictionaries. `get_average()` is a function that calculates average and it works fine. When I try to call the function `get_class_average()` I'm getting error:

```
typeerror string indices must be integers not str
```

My code

```
lloyd = {
    "name": "Lloyd",
    "homework": [90.0, 97.0, 75.0, 92.0],
    "quizzes": [88.0, 40.0, 94.0],
    "tests": [75.0, 90.0]
}
alice = {
    "name": "Alice",
    "homework": [100.0, 92.0, 98.0, 100.0],
    "quizzes": [82.0, 83.0, 91.0],
    "tests": [89.0, 97.0]
}
tyler = {
    "name": "Tyler",
    "homework": [0.0, 87.0, 75.0, 22.0],
    "quizzes": [0.0, 75.0, 78.0],
    "tests": [100.0, 100.0]
}

# Add your function below!
from math import *
def average(numbers):
    total = sum(numbers)
    total = float(total)
    ans = total / len(numbers)
    return ans
num = [1,2,4,5,6]
a = average(num)
print a

def get_average(student):
    homework = average(student["homework"])
    quizzes = average(student["quizzes"])
    tests = average(student["tests"])
    sum = (0.1*homework) + (0.3 * quizzes) + (0.6 * tests)
    return sum

student = [lloyd, alice, tyler]
for key in student:   
    a = get_average(key)
    print a

def get_letter_grade(score):
    if score >= 90:
        return "A"
    elif score >= 80:
        return "B"
    elif score >= 70:
        return "C"
    elif score >= 60:
        return "D"
    else:
        return "F"

avg = get_average(lloyd)
t = get_letter_grade(avg)
print t


def get_class_average(students):
    results = []
    students = [lloyd, alice, tyler]
    a= get_average(students)
    r= results.append(a)
    return r

student = [lloyd, alice, tyler]
for key in student:   
    a = get_class_average(key)

print a
```

Comment: where  is `get_average`?

Comment: It's not `for key in students` but `for student in students` that is actually being executed!

Comment: You are passing in individual students to the `get_class_average()` function, but your function *expects* a list of students.

Answer (score 0):

Your `get_class_average()` function expects to be passed the whole list of students, not each individual student.

Remove your `for key in student:` loop:

```
students = [lloyd, alice, tyler]
a = get_class_average(students)
```

Within the `get_class_average()` function you appear to be returning *too early*; unindent the `return` to not be part of the loop. `results.append()` returns `None` as it alters `results` *in-place*:

```
def get_class_average(students):
    results = []
    for key in students:   
        a= get_average(key)
        results.append(a)
    return results
```

This still doesn't calculate the average for the whole class, however; it just collects the averages for each student into a list.

Comment: Seems like there are a lot of other problems too.

Comment: i tried this:  students = [lloyd, alice, tyler]
a = get_class_average(students)  but still the same error

Comment: @AashkaKotecha: then add `get_average()` to your question, and the actual full traceback you see.